# Reset Chrome website permissions

Tags: permissions, chrome-for-android, webcam

How can I reset website permissions on Chrome for Android?

I have face detection software hosted on my home server (192.168.1.7:8020), and if I go to 192.168.1.7:8020/face-detection.html I used to get a notification about my tablet camera usage. Every time I clicked "allow" it would work.

But I missed "allow" button today and clicked "reject". Now I can't find where or how to reset media permissions for this particular page/site.

I'm on Nexus 10 with Android 4.2.2 (3.4.5-gaf9c307) using Chrome 26.0.1410.58 with WebRTC flag on.

Comment: I'd imagine clearing the cache/data would work but you'd also lose everything else, I'd hope there's a better way.

Comment: @Peanut Thought about this too while was posting but let's wait maybe there's another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Menu - Settings - Content settings - Website settings

From there you can clear data for individual sites.

If that doesn't work, maybe look into Remote USB Debugging: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: Thanks, I tried "Website Settings" already but I think (probably I'm wrong) Chrome doesn't track sites that don't have fqdn, so my 192.168.1.X aren't on the list. Will look into Remote Debug.

Answer (score 0):

You can't clear website settings. This is a major oversight in my opinion.